# Safely Making Minor Postgres Upgrade

Tags: macos, postgresql, terminal, homebrew, postgresql-9.5

I currently have postgres 9.5.2 installed on my Mac OSX machine. I want to upgrade it to postgres 9.5.4 (which is not the latest 9.5.X version). What is the best way of doing this? I installed Postgres initially via homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown the database, upgrade the software, start the database with the new software. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html) will tell you that minor upgrades are binary compatible.